# IBM SBT :Expectation Failed error

Tags: javascript, connection, ibm-sbt

After working on SBT for such long time to get the forum section working in my existing application now iam facing the weird error.I have connected to w3 connections and implemented the forum section in my existing application and able to add topics and comments in w3 connections using SBT.

It is going well from many days with forceDisableExpectedContinue in managed beans as false but suddenly it started giving one weird error and that is "Expectation Failed".

When goggled found that i should add the System.Net.ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false; in code but iam using javascript code to get the access to w3 connections.

I added forceDisableExpectedContinue in managed beans to true and checked, it is working fine.But initially it was true still i got this error.I doubt that is it the problem solved because of restart or any other issue.It is not consistent behavior to track the root cause.Need to deploy the same in production and not able to say application is working fine.

FYI my application will connect through the IHS server.Do i need to add anything in managed-beans.xml ?

Chat section for support is much appreciated and useful instead of Stackoverflow for immediate support.

Access this link for better understanding https://dst05lp3.lexington.ibm.com/SBTTest/discussionForum.html?forumUuid=0d2e2f15-c014-41a0-aba6-634d3c72d981&pageGuid=MBC

Change the forumid and pageguid(tagname) to the one you have forum access .
Thanks in advance.

Comment: you are most likely using a reverse proxy in front. you do not need to anything to your managed beans.xml, as long as you have modified the URL to reflect the ihs port.

Comment: i investigated and found that in managed-beans.xml we shud change the forceDisableExpectedContinue to true and it worked fine .because i got this error again for the old SBT application which was running in my test server and when i chenged the forceDisableExpectedContinue to true then error is not coming .So hoping it resolved for now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When trying with the old code suddenly iam getting the same error then changed the forceDisableExpectedContinue in managed-beans.xml and it got resolved .Hoping it is resolved closing this question.If found again then my resolution is wrong.
Thanks paul for giving bit support.